# Mandating target process id in git commit

Tags: git, github, targetprocess

How to mandate the target process id in git commit. I know the way of writing the hooks but don't know how to validate whether mentioned target process id is valid or not. github is being used as git host.
Want something like follows:

1. User will do 'git commit' with format like below:

   TargetProcess ticket id:

   Detailed description:....
2. Now user will push this branch to GitHub. Here, push should fail if mentioned  is not available in targetprocess. If mentioned ticket number is valid, then allow push.

Comment: target process? As in "https://www.targetprocess.com/guide/main/domain-model/"?

Comment: Something like https://marketplace.atlassian.com/apps/1213415/commit-policy-for-jira-git-svn-hg?hosting=server&tab=overview&_ga=2.139145521.341703958.1542715937-1002201699.1542715937 in targetprocess

Comment: OK. Can you edit your question with a bit more information?